# Use of the schema-element node test in XSD 1.1's assert test

Tags: xsd

I am trying to design a XML schema where a certain element may alternatively hold either a single element belonging to a substitution group or a collection of certain elements which I want to be free-order (like in "all").

Due to the limitations on the "all" type of groups I cannot nest it into a "choice", so I tried a design which is similar to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="X" abstract="true"/>
    <xs:element name="X1" substitutionGroup="X"/>
    <xs:element name="X2" substitutionGroup="X"/>
    <xs:element name="Y">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element ref="X" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Z1" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Z2" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Z3" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:all>
            <xs:assert test="not(schema-element(X)) or not(Z1 or Z2 or Z3)"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

When the schema file is validated, I get the following error:

```
File C:\whereabouts\xsd-assertion-problem.xsd is not valid.
    Assertion 'not(schema-element(X)) or not(Z)' is no valid XPath 2.0 expression.
        Error location: xs:schema / xs:element / xs:complexType / xs:assert
        Details
            XPST0008: Element name not found in static context's in-scope element declarations
            as-props-correct.2: Assertion 'not(schema-element(X)) or not(Z)' is no valid XPath 2.0 expression.
```

The question is: what is wrong here and how to fix it? When I read (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#ERRXPST0008)[the description of XPath error condition], it explicitly excludes "an ElementName in an ElementTest", which should be the case here, so static analysis should not fail here. Or am I wrong?

Note that the substitution group for `X` is open for extension and finding all locations where references to `X` are made may be difficult, that's why I strongly prefer to use a `schema-element`-based test.

On the other hand, while writing `Z1 or Z2 or Z3` is also cumbersome, these elements are local, so this solution is more or less acceptable. Of course, if there are better ideas, they are welcome!

Just in case, I rely on the Altova engine.

Comment: Validated you schema in Oxygen. No errors.

Comment: @PavelKoryakin, thank you for the report. Apparently a bug in the engine then. I'll resort to other methods of assertion then.